# When I run my code it display random symbols at the end

Tags: c++, for-loop, c-strings

I am separating a string into words and when I run the source code, it works but at the end it displays random symbols and letter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;


void seperatestring(string str);
 

int main()
{
    string str;
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    getline(cin, str);
    seperatestring(str);
    return 0;
}

void seperatestring(string str)
{
    string word = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str[str.size()-1] ; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
        {
            cout << word << endl;
            word = "";
        }
        else {
            word = word + str[i];
        }
    }
    cout << word << endl;
}
```

This is the source code. The only problem is that at the end of the result there are random symbols and letters. What should I fix in my source code to remove the random symbols at the end?

Comment: "The only problem is that at the end of the result there are random symbols and letters." What does this mean? Please show an example (copy and paste text from the terminal, formatted like code) of what happens when you try to run the code and provide input.

Comment: Think carefully about the code. Where it says `for (int i = 0; i < str[str.size()-1] ; i++)`, what do you think this means? What is the largest value that you expect `i` to have, and why? (Hint: what result do you expect from `str.size() - 1`? What happens if you use that as an index into `str`? What happens if you compare *that result* to `i`? What result should be compared to `i` instead?)

Comment: The following isn't an answer to your question. However to illustrate the importance of learning the standard library I sketched out [This code](https://godbolt.org/z/de3YcKTnc). It was heavily inspired by [this cppreference.com page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/split_view).
I use the aforementioned websites every single day. I hope you find them useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks suspicious:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str[str.size()-1] ; i++)
```

Don't you really mean:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
```